# collatz c code logical error

Tags: c, collatz

```
static void collatz(int i)
{
    int x=0,a=0,res=0,count=0;
    int array[50];
    array[0]=i;
    while(array[count]!=0)
    {
        if(array[count]%2==0)
        {
            count++;
            array[count]=i/2;
        }
        else
        {
            count++;
            array[count]=3*array[count-1]-1;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int a;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    collatz(a);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run the code, I enter 8 as "a" and console crushes itself. I'm using dev c.
Sorry for my awful english but I hope I'm clear enough.

Comment: try: `while(array[count]!=0 && count<50)`

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 for 8 collatz sequence is 8 4 2 1, so there can't be a problem with count

Comment: if that's what he wants, `array[count]=i/2;` should be `array[count]=array[count-1]/2;`..

Comment: problem is the while part

Comment: since we don't know what kind of output you want, it's kinda difficult to predict the solution..

Comment: maybe this means problem solved, right, @user3278628?

Answer (score 0):

I count four errors:

- The loop should terminate when `array[count]` is `1`, not `0`
- You should check that `count` is less than 49
- `array[count]=i/2` should be `array[count]=array[count-1]/2`
- `array[count]=3*array[count-1]-1` should be `array[count]=3*array[count-1]+1`

So the code with these issues fixed, and some slight shortening, could be:

```
static void collatz(int i) {
    int count=0;
    int array[50];
    array[0]=i;
    while (count < 49) {
        int j = array[count++];
        if (j == 1)
           break;
        else if(j % 2 == 0)
            array[count]=j/2;
        else
            array[count]=3*j+1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first, the while loop is wrong, you should end the while when `array[count] == 1`, so you can use `while(array[count] > 1)` to test.

second, `array[count]=i/2;` is wrong, you shuld use `array[count]=array[count-1]/2;`.

Third, you should check the `count < 50`, because you declare `int array[50];`.

```
static void collatz(int i) 
{
    int x=0,a=0,res=0,count=0;
    int array[50]= {0};
    array[0]=i;
    while(array[count] > 1 && count < 50)
    {
        if(array[count]%2==0)
        {
            count++;
            array[count]=array[count-1]/2;
        }
        else
        {
            count++;
            array[count]=3*array[count-1]-1;
        }
    }
}
```